# Elementary question about the Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, notation

I need to calculate the Euler-Lagrange equation for a given Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$, that depends on a field $\phi=\phi(t,x)$. The statement of the problem provides me with the following expression for this equation:

$$\partial_\mu\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}-\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}=0.$$

I believe the expression of the Lagrangian density isn't relevant to my question, but in case it is, its expression is

$$\mathcal{L}=\dfrac{1}{2}\big[(\partial_t\phi)^2-(\partial_x\phi^2)\big]-a(\phi^2-b).$$

I suppose that, following the standard notation, the index $\mu$ stands for the two variables $t$ and $x$. So, we have one function, $\phi$, that depends on the two variables $x$ and $t$. However, I'm unsure of whether this means we will have two Euler-Lagrange equations, one where $\mu=t$ and another where $\mu=x$, or if there is an implicit summation according to Einstein's convention. So, am I dealing with

$$\begin{array}{c} \partial_t\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_t\phi)}-\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}=0 \\ \partial_x\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_x\phi)}-\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}=0\end{array}$$

or what exactly? I'm told later on, in order to solve for $\phi$, that $\phi$ is time-independent, that is, $\phi=\phi(x)$. Does this mean that the first equation of the system is eliminated?

Comment: As @Photon explained, you want one equation, $\partial_t\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_t\phi}+\partial_x\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_x\phi}-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}=0$. It's actually easier to write the kinetic sector as $\frac12\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi$, as then you can do the whole calculation with a contraction, rather than going through the $\mu$ values one by one.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you very much for your help! Actually, that's the way the Lagrangian density was originally written, but I don't feel confident using that notation yet since the metric is implied and I would probably mess up the signs when derivating, so I rewrote it. I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: OK, but once you're comfortable with this notation you'll be able to speed through$$\begin{align}\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}&=\partial_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\frac{\partial^\nu\phi\partial_\nu\phi}{2}\\&=\partial_\mu(\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)\\&=\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi\\&=\square\phi.\end{align}$$

Comment: @J.G. If μ appears in both instances as a lower index, why is summation implied? thx

Comment: @YoA It's actually once down once up; $\frac{\partial A}{\partial B_\mu}$ counts as upstairs, viz. $dA=\frac{\partial A}{\partial B_\mu}dB_\mu=\frac{\partial A}{\partial B^\mu}dB^\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a summation implied, so there is only one equation. When $\phi$ is time-independent, then the term involving the time derivative vanishes from this one equation.

You get several equations, when more than one field is involved, similar to the case of several coordinates in the classical mechanics case.

Comment: Do you mean that, in the case of several coordinates in the classical mechanics case, we have several coordinates which all depend on t, same as if we had several fields $\phi_i(t)$ here with i ranging from 1 to n? So, several independent variables add more terms to the same equation, and several independent variables add more equations? Thank you!

Comment: In the case of a (quantum) field theory each field adds a new Euler Lagrange equation, in the case of a (classical) mechanics each spatial coordinate adds a new Euler Lagrange equation.

Answer (score 1):

The mnenomic is relatively easy if you compare with the EOMs for point particles.  The fields replace the point particles and $t$ is replaced by the all coordinates of the field.  Thus:

- There is *one* EL equation for each point particle (or each degree of freedom), so there will be *one* EL equation for each field,
- the position $q_k$ of point particle $k$ is $q_k(t)$ (or $q_1=x(t), q_2=y(t)$ etc.), i.e. it depends only *one* parameter $t$  for point particles, so there is only *one* derivative w/r to this *one* parameter.  For fields, $\phi$ is a function $\phi(x,t)$ so there will be a *sum* of derivative, one derivative for each parameter.

Thus, if you have $2$ degrees of freedom $q_1$ and $q_2$ or two fields $\phi_1(x,t)$ and $\phi_2(x,t)$:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\frac{dq_a}{dt}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_a}=0\quad 
\Rightarrow \quad 
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial\frac{\partial \phi_a}{\partial t} }
+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial\frac{\partial \phi_a}{\partial x} }\right)-\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi_a}=0
$$
where $a=1,2$.  From there you can use the summation sign over coordinate indices using $(x_1,x_2)=(x,t)$:
$$
\sum_{\mu}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}}
\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial \phi_{a,\mu})} 
-\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi_a}=0 \qquad \mu=1,2\, .
$$